# C++ overload operator twice, one return non-const reference and the other const reference, what is the preference?

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, constants, operator-keyword

I overload an operator twice with the same parameter list. but with different return type:

```
T& operator()(par_list){blablabla}    
const T& operator()(par_list){blablabla}
```

So when I'm calling the () operator, which function would be called based on what preference or situation? I know that if I call () under const function it has to be the const T& one.

I'm just curious how C++ deal with such situation and how the default preference works.

Thanks

Comment: The term is *overload*, and no.

Comment: C++ Disallows overload by return type.  One could go into what it 'could/should' do, but it won't matter.  One trick is to make the method const when the return type is const, as that can be overloaded.  My memory is the const method is preferred, with non-const being called the const call would not be legal.

Comment: To answer your question, use the const obj& fxn() const version when you are not modifying the return object.  use obj& fxn() when you need to modify the return argument.  For example, if you have a class with a composition relationship, i.e. attribute is an object, you may wish to return the object by reference when you need to modify it. Otherwise, when you only need to access it's information through, e.g. a getter, but don't need to modify the object you can have both a: const obj& get() const  and obj& get() version coexist.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

These functions don't overload each other; they have the same signatures, and so the attempt to redefine the same function, which is an error. The return type is not part of a function's signature. To overload a function, you must declare a second function with the same name, but different parameters or `const`/`volatile` qualifiers - that is, qualifiers on the function, not the return type.

(They don't override each other either; overriding is what derived classes do to their base classes' virtual functions).

It's common to define a `const` and a non-`const` overload of a member function; the `const` overload must declare the function `const`, not just the return type:

```
T& operator()(par_list){blablabla}
const T& operator()(par_list) const {blablabla}
                              ^^^^^
```

Now the first will be called if you apply `()` to a non-`const` object, and the second on a `const` object. For example:

```
Thingy nc;
Thingy const c;

nc(); // calls the first (non-const) overload
c();  // calls the second (const) overload
```

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: OK, I didn't realise "signature" included return type. Is there an official term for "the bits that determine which overload to choose"?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Maybe you can clarify this because it seems to have changed since C++03. `§1.3.18` seems to refer to template functions. But the entries for non template (free or member) functions make no mention of return values. Neither do entries for template function specializations.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You are right, removing the comment. Mike, a careful reread of the standard indicates that for function templates (as Juancho mentions) the return type is part of the signature. For regular functions the signature does not include the return type. C++03 has a footnote: *Function signatures do not include return type, because that does not participate in overload resolution.* Sorry for introducing confusion to the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't overload a function/method based on return type. I would expect the compiler to throw an error here. What you can do is specify the method itself as a `const` method, using

```
const T& operator()(par_list) const {blahblah}
```

The `const` qualifier not only means this can be called on a `const` receiver, but it also is used in the overload resolution. This happens because it affects the implicit `*this` parameter that's passed to the method; a `const` method uses a `const` qualifier on `*this`, and `const` qualifiers are taken into account during overload resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The way you define your operators, no way the compiler can decide which operator() to call. Overloading of functions (and operators) can only be done on the type of the arguments, never on the return type. And in fact, you will have an error at compilation as soon as you define the second one, the compiler considering that you are redefining the same function/operator.

However, the following is common (and probably what you have):

```
T& operator()(par_list){blablabla}
const T& operator()(par_list) const {blablabla}
```

This additional "const" after the argument list exists because you are defining non-static member functions and member functions have an implicit hidden argument: the "this" pointer to the instance of the class. The "const" keyword there indicates if this hidden pointer is to a const instance or not. This argument participates to the overloading resolution and that is in this case what the compiler use to choose which version of the operator to use.

So:

```
class A {
    T& operator()() { ... }
    const T& operator()() const { .... }
};

A a;
const A& ca(a);
a(); -> returns a T&
ca(); -> returns a const T&
```